# How do sum values in dictionary based on some condition?

Tags: python

Well I have this kind of dictionary where Token number is the key . Inside we have name and strike also the key. I want to filter out those keys and values where Strike is same and name contains the stock name. 
So lets say TATASTEEL is the stock name and strike is 540. So I want to filter this out and will get 2 dictionary items for this i.e. 22958594: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC540PE', 'Strike': 540.0}, 22958338: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC540CE', 'Strike': 540.0}

```
22958594: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC540PE', 'Strike': 540.0}, 
22958338: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC540CE', 'Strike': 540.0}, 
22958082: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC530PE', 'Strike': 530.0},
22957826: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC530CE', 'Strike': 530.0}, 
22957570: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC520PE', 'Strike': 520.0}, 
22957314: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC520CE', 'Strike': 520.0},
22957058: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC510PE', 'Strike': 510.0}, 
22956802: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC510CE', 'Strike': 510.0}, 
22956546: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC500PE', 'Strike': 500.0},
22956290: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC500CE', 'Strike': 500.0}, 
22956034: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC490PE', 'Strike': 490.0}, 
22955778: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC490CE', 'Strike': 490.0},
22955522: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC480PE', 'Strike': 480.0}, 
22955266: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC480CE', 'Strike': 480.0}, 
22955010: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC470PE', 'Strike': 470.0},
22954754: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC470CE', 'Strike': 470.0}, 
22954498: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC460PE', 'Strike': 460.0},
```

Comment: Is this a dictionary object with the values again being dictionaries? Please post a minimal reproducible example so people can understand your problem better: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple approaches to this you need to be a bit more specific on how exactly you want to filter. but to show an example of what was requested above i would go something like this.

```
original_data = {22958594: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC540PE', 'Strike': 540.0}, 22958338: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC540CE', 'Strike': 540.0}, 22958082: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC530PE', 'Strike': 530.0},
 22957826: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC530CE', 'Strike': 530.0}, 22957570: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC520PE', 'Strike': 520.0}, 22957314: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC520CE', 'Strike': 520.0},
 22957058: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC510PE', 'Strike': 510.0}, 22956802: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC510CE', 'Strike': 510.0}, 22956546: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC500PE', 'Strike': 500.0},
 22956290: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC500CE', 'Strike': 500.0}, 22956034: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC490PE', 'Strike': 490.0}, 22955778: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC490CE', 'Strike': 490.0},
 22955522: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC480PE', 'Strike': 480.0}, 22955266: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC480CE', 'Strike': 480.0}, 22955010: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC470PE', 'Strike': 470.0},
 22954754: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC470CE', 'Strike': 470.0}, 22954498: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC460PE', 'Strike': 460.0}}

strike = 540

stock_name = 'TATASTEEL'

filtered_data = {k:v for k, v in original_data.items() if v['Strike']==strike and v['name'].startswith(stock_name)}
```

Comment: If you want groupings of different strike values, then you can make a set of all available strike values as follows 
set_of_strike_values = { item["Strike"] for item in original_data.values() }
and then filter by set_of_strike_values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pandas here:

```
d = {
 22958594: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC540PE', 'Strike': 540.0},
 22958338: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC540CE', 'Strike': 540.0},
 22958082: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC530PE', 'Strike': 530.0},
 22957826: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC530CE', 'Strike': 530.0},
 22957570: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC520PE', 'Strike': 520.0},
 22957314: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC520CE', 'Strike': 520.0},
 22957058: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC510PE', 'Strike': 510.0},
 22956802: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC510CE', 'Strike': 510.0},
 22956546: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC500PE', 'Strike': 500.0},
 22956290: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC500CE', 'Strike': 500.0},
 22956034: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC490PE', 'Strike': 490.0},
 22955778: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC490CE', 'Strike': 490.0},
 22955522: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC480PE', 'Strike': 480.0},
 22955266: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC480CE', 'Strike': 480.0},
 22955010: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC470PE', 'Strike': 470.0},
 22954754: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC470CE', 'Strike': 470.0},
 22954498: {'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC460PE', 'Strike': 460.0}}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d).T    # .T was used for transpose of dataframe

print(df[df.name.str.contains('TATASTEEL') & (df.Strike == 540)].T.to_dict())  # here i used boolean indexing
```

**Output**

```
{22958594: {'Strike': 540.0, 'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC540PE'}, 
22958338: {'Strike': 540.0, 'name': 'TATASTEEL19DEC540CE'}}
```